# installation guideline for new progammers in team

Tags: c#, document

I want to prepare document to be served as guideline for new programmers which should be part of our team. This document should describe installation path, from new windows installation to visual studio, etc. After installing all this from doc. new programmer should be ready to code (everything set up).

Do you have such recommendation how to do this? Is there any standards for this? Do you have sample documents willing to share?

Comment: You might want to ask this on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) which FAQ allows _discussion_ of "design patterns,
developer testing,
development methodologies".

Answer (score 2):

I think not only writing down a setup guide is enough by itself. We are writing guidance documents and samples on how to code. It is a document which first states a scenario and shows every step of coding.

Also, instead of setting up the environment each time a developer starts working, just setup up a new machine with all related settings, and take the image of this computer. Then, just copy this image to the new developer's computer.

Comment: we already have coding standards document. So you basically do not have installation setup guide, you use all preinstalled and store on the image, is that right?

Comment: In fact we do have; but that is just because of the standarts; if your development environment is subject to change, you may need to change the image too. The choice depends on the effort on creating a new image. On the other hand, most of the time, developers have to start working immediately, which makes the image as a first choice. Also, the coding document I mentioned is not just a standarts document. It is better to have a coding standarts document, but what I mentioned is for more practical issues; for instance how to write a new WCF service method using the existing infrastructure.

Comment: are you willing to share installation guide doc, or maybe some link which you follow when making installation doc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that just like any guide it should be kept to stupid simple. Do not assume anything, or else, if you make any assumptions, state them clearly.